# Can't display PSObject

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to display some data my script generates in a PSObject, so I can then export to a CSV, but the only object that shows is whichever one I add to the array first.

```
$pass=@("1","2","3")
$fail=@("4")
$obj=@()
$pass | % {
    $obj+=New-Object PSObject -Property @{Pass=$_}
}
$fail | % {
    $obj+=New-Object PSObject -Property @{Fail=$_}
}
$obj
```

I've also tried this, but I get a blank line showing in the table where the value isn't in that column, which I don't want:

```
$pass=@("1","2","3")
$fail=@("4")
$obj=@()
$pass | % {
    $obj+=New-Object PSObject -Property @{Pass=$_;Fail=""}
}
$fail | % {
    $obj+=New-Object PSObject -Property @{Pass="";Fail=$_}
}
$obj
```

My desired result:

```
Pass    Fail
----    ----
1       4
2
3
```

I am using Powershell V2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you figured out yourself, PowerShell only outputs the properties of the *first item* in your array. Its **not designed** to print the ouput you are expecting in the way you are using it.

---

As a workaround, you could use a `for` loop to "build" your desired output:

```
$pass=@("1","2","3")
$fail=@("4")
$obj=@()

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $pass.Count; $i++)
{
    if ($fail.Count -gt $i)
    {
        $currentFail = $fail[$i]
    }
    else
    {
        $currentFail = ""
    }

    $obj+=New-Object PSObject -Property @{Fail=$currentFail;Pass=$pass[$i];}
}
$obj | select Pass, Fail
```

**Output:**

```
Pass Fail
---- ----
1    4   
2        
3
```

Comment: You are welcome. Be aware that you won't see all records if `$pass.count` is less then `$fail.count`. If this could be the case, you have to adpot the script.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer is right - you're using objects wrong.  That being said, here's a function to help you use them wrong!

```
Function New-BadObjectfromArray($array1,$array2,$array1name,$array2name){
    if ($array1.count -ge $array2.count){$iteratorCount = $array1.count}
    else {$iteratorCount = $array2.count}
    $obj = @()
    $iteration=0
    while ($iteration -le $iteratorCount){
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            $array1name=$array1[$iteration]
            $array2name=$array2[$iteration]
        }
        $iteration += 1
    }
    $obj
}

$pass=@("1","2","3")
$fail=@("4")

New-BadObjectfromArray -array1 $fail -array2 $pass -array1name "Fail" -array2name "Pass"
```

Comment: I receive an exception: `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

Comment: I ran it again - mine must silently continue - are you at least getting output?

Comment: If I set the `$ErrorActionPreference` to SilentlyContinue, I receive just one line: 
`Fail Pass
---- ----
4    1   `

Comment: Love the function name xD

Comment: $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major ?  Mine is 5.